# What are the masses of the docking / berthing mechanisms used by the ISS?

Tags: iss, docking, docking-port, mass, berthing

I have been unable to find any information on the masses of the docking / berthing mechanisms used by the ISS. What are the masses of the APAS-95, Active / Passive Common Berthing Mechanism, and Russian probe / drogue docking systems? The best I can find is the mass of the PMA's, the lightest one is [1183 kg](http://www.nasa.gov/externalflash/ISSRG/pdfs/pma.pdf), which consists of a passive CBM + permanently passive APAS + additional structure.

Comment: And it is going to get odd, since the NDS (Nasa Docking System) Dragon is bringing on SPX-7 or so is going to 'plug into' the current PMA so how do you count the mass then?  Whole system?  Each component?

Answer (score 1):

Partial:

Apparently, APAS-95 had a mass of 286 kg

https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Twenty_first_Century_in_Space/BH7ZBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0